# Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and Postgresql configuration "password authentication failed"

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

**Contents of Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Contents of docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgresdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
      - POSTGRES_USER=user1
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    volumes:
      - pgdb-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 

  levelupworks:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=levelworks
      - DB_USER=user1
      - DB_PASS=password
      - DB_HOST=db
    command: > 
      bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations
      && python manage.py migrate
      && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    image: levelupworks-image
    container_name: levelupworks-app
    ports:
      - "10555:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  pgdb-data:
    driver: local
```

**Contents of settings.py:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
    }
}
```

Output of: "**docker logs levelupworks-app**"

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:105: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user1"

  warnings.warn(
No changes detected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user1"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1290, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1681, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes or
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/features.py", line 93, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 329, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user1"
```

**WHAT HAVE I DONE WRONG? PLEASE HELP** I have literally spent all night chasing my tail, can someone please tell me where I have gone wrong in my implementation of docker-compose and Postgresql?I will be very appreciative to some suggestions and explanations.

Comment: Which PORT of postgresql do you try to connect to? Shouldn't your DB_HOST include that port? Depending on version of postgres it could look like that: DB_HOST=db:5432

Comment: I changed DB_HOST=db:5432 as suggested but that did not help running docker ps -a shows the container exiting upon build.

Comment: Your DB names are different in the DB container and the app container, either set POSTGRES_DB=levelworks in the postgres container or DB_NAME=levelworks in the app container

Comment: Hi @Dalvtor I have changed the structure of the docker-compose file a little and have added a .env file with python-decouple installed in pip.  So the names are not in conflict anymore I dont think. still getting the same errors